# Windows Forms - How to move a picture box up when stretching the form

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

So, I have a situation in windows forms (Visual Studio / C#) that is similar to this :

[image]

Right now, as you can see, there is no sufficient space beside picturebox number 3 to fit picturebox number 4. However, if the user stretches the form to the right, there will be enough space.

My doubt: Is there an easy way to make picturebox number 4 move up if, after the user stretches the form, there is enough space? I tried all kinds of anchors, but it does not go up. It goes to the right as the form stretches, but does not move up beside picturebox 3.

Thank you all.

Comment: A FlowLayoutPanel may do it for you.  I've never tried it though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-a-flowlayoutpanel

Comment: Anchored FlowLayoutPanel with `FlowDirection = LeftToRight`